# Download several pdfs from a list of links which require login (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize, pdfkit

This is my first post here. I am trying to download several pdf files from a website that requires login. I managed to get all the links that include the pdfs I want and stored them in a list. However, I am not able to download the pdfs. Below you can find my code. Please note that I didn't include several information such as the original website etc.

```
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1)
br.addheaders = [( 'User-Agent', headers)]
br.open(mainwebsite)

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = myusername
br.form['password'] = mypassword
br.submit(id="loginbtn")

url = br.open(websitewherepdfsarelocated)
returnPage = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(returnPage)
links = soup.findAll('a')
test=[]
for link in links:
    test.append(link.get('href'))
for i in test[:]:
    if i is None:
        test.remove(i)
    elif i.startswith('https://....(website).....view.php?id='): # links which pdf are 
        print(i)
    else:
        test.remove(i)
```

So now I have a list of links in the 'test' list that I want to download. While trying to find a solution, I came across to the pdfkit and tried to get the pdf of a link that obtained earlier (was stored in test) using the below code but I was getting a pdf showing the login page.

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url("https://......(website)......view.php?id=........", 'out.pdf')
```

Thanking you in advance!